# Rx CatchAll for unobserved messages

Tags: c#, .net, linq, system.reactive

I'm wondering if it would be possible to setup some kind of catch-all for an Rx `IObservable`.

It would behave along the lines of: "if no other subscriber has observed this message, then do [something]".

Right now I wire up several Observable handlers that know not of each other, and filter events based on certain properties. I want to throw an error if we receive a message that is not being handled because it would be an invalid message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought this was an interesting problem, so I went and wrote a moderately sized solution. I've broken the solution into three parts: the general purpose implementation, an example usage, and an explanation.

## Implementation

```cs
public interface ITracked<out T>
{
    T Value { get; }
    bool IsObserved { get; }
    void Observe();
}

public class Tracked<T> : ITracked<T>
{
    private readonly T value;
    public Tracked(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public T Value
    {
        get { return value; }
    }
    public bool IsObserved { get; private set; }
    public void Observe()
    {
        IsObserved = true;
    }
}

public interface ITrackableObservable<out T> : IObservable<ITracked<T>>
{
    IObservable<T> Unobserved { get; }
}

public class TrackableObservable<T> : ITrackableObservable<T>
{
    private readonly ISubject<T> unobserved = new Subject<T>();
    private readonly IObservable<ITracked<T>> source;

    public TrackableObservable(IObservable<T> source)
    {
        this.source = Observable
            .Create<ITracked<T>>(observer => source.Subscribe(
                value =>
                {
                    var trackedValue = new Tracked<T>(value);
                    observer.OnNext(trackedValue);
                    if (!trackedValue.IsObserved)
                    {
                        unobserved.OnNext(value);
                    }
                },
                observer.OnError,
                observer.OnCompleted))
            .Publish()
            .RefCount();
    }

    public IObservable<T> Unobserved
    {
        get { return unobserved.AsObservable(); }
    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<ITracked<T>> observer)
    {
        return source.Subscribe(observer);
    }
}

public static class TrackableObservableExtensions
{
    public static ITrackableObservable<T> ToTrackableObservable<T>(this IObservable<T> source)
    {
        return new TrackableObservable<T>(source);
    }

    public static IObservable<T> Observe<T>(this IObservable<ITracked<T>> source)
    {
        return source.Do(x => x.Observe()).Select(x => x.Value);
    }

    public static IObservable<T> ObserveWhere<T>(this IObservable<ITracked<T>> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        return source.Where(x => predicate(x.Value)).Observe();
    }
}
```

## Example

```
public class Animal
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Kind { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

...

IObservable<Animal> animals = ...;
ITrackableObservable<Animal> trackableAnimals = animals.ToTrackableObservable();
trackableAnimals
    .ObserveWhere(a => a.Kind == "Cat")
    .Subscribe(a => Console.WriteLine("{0}: Meow", a.ID));
trackableAnimals
    .ObserveWhere(a => a.Kind == "Dog")
    .Subscribe(a => Console.WriteLine("{0}: Woof", a.ID));
trackableAnimals
    .ObserveWhere(a => a.Name != null)
    .Subscribe(a => Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} named {2}", a.ID, a.Kind, a.Name));
trackableAnimals
    .Unobserved
    .Subscribe(a => Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} with no name (unobserved)", a.ID, a.Kind));
```

If `animals` were to emit this sequence:

```
new Animal { ID = 1, Kind = "Cat", Name = "Rusty" }
new Animal { ID = 2, Kind = "Horse" }
new Animal { ID = 3, Kind = "Dog", Name = "Fido" }
new Animal { ID = 4, Kind = "Dog" }
new Animal { ID = 5, Kind = "Bird", Name = "Simon" }
```

Then we would see this output:

```
1: Meow
1: Cat named Rusty
2: Horse with no name (unobserved)
3: Woof
3: Dog named Fido
4: Woof
5: Bird named Simon
```

## Explanation

The idea here is to ensure that all subscribers ultimately share a single subscription to the source sequence, and that every value has a `bool` attached to it that says whether that value has been observed or not. Whenever the source sequence emits a `T`, we wrap it as an `ITracked<T>` and then pass that single instance on to all of the subscribers. Observers can then mark the value as observed if they choose to. Once all `OnNext` calls on observers have returned, if the `ITracked<T>` is not marked as observed, then we know that it was unobserved.

The `TrackableObservableExtensions` class provides a few extension methods that make working with the implementation more fluent, but they aren't required as part of the implementation.

Comment: Really neat solution, pointed me in the right direction. thanks!